# Exit status of chained commands

Tags: pipe, exit-status, dash

I want to run a potentially invalid command in a variable `cmd`. I can't afford to have it just fail me and retrieve the exit status. What I can try to do is pipe it to `:` and then I'll have a successful exit status.

```
$ $cmd | :
$ echo $?
0
```

Now, I want to know the exit status of `cmd` without running it by itself. In Bash I would be able to accomplish this using `PIPESTATUS`. But I'm using dash.

I tried to run `bash -c "$cmd | : ; rc=$(echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]} | head -c1)"` but I get a "Bad substituion error".

My questions are:

1. How do accomplish my goal of returning the exit status of the first command in dash?
2. What is it about what I'm doing that yields an error in dash?

Comment: Why do you need this at all?  Just let `cmd` exit how it wants?

Comment: Because then, things that are outside of my control won't work. I can feed a file with commands to be ran and for some reason if any of the commands fails, the script won't work in some sense. (What sense this is, I can't even tell because I don't have enough visibility/access over what's happening). So I need to make sure that each line is successful. As part of my needs, I also require the exit status of what I referenced above as `cmd`. @Jesse_b

Comment: I don't understand.  Your script should not exit from a single command failure.  I don't think `pipefail` is even available in dash

Comment: @Jesse_b `set -e` probably...

Comment: @Jesse_b The script doesn't actually exit. I don't know in exactly what happens, but something stops working and if I can make sure there are no invalid commands, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the full shell syntax available to you, then you can use `if`, which does not appear as a failure to the shell:

```shell
if (eval "$cmd"); then
    : # do nothing, it worked
else
    printf 'Command %s failed with code %d\n' "$cmd" $?
fi
```

Note that you can't use the more obvious `if ! eval…` syntax, as the negation will hide the exit code. The "do nothing" bit there is there because shell syntax *requires* a then block with a command in it; you can't omit it or leave it empty.

The important thing is that an `if` is not a failure to the shell, even though the evaluated command failed.

The parentheses are to run the command in a sub-shell; this prevents the command from e.g., setting variables that affect your script or doing something like `exit 1` to kill your script entirely.

Finally, note how I've used `eval` instead of unquoted `$cmd`. That's because unquoted command does word splitting in a way you probably don't expect. If you had `cmd='rm -Rf "foo * baz"'`, then when you run `$cmd` what you're actually running is `rm -Rf \"foo * baz\"` — which *will* expand the `*` to all files in the directory, deleting everything (in addition to the two files `"foo` and `baz"`). That's three arguments to `rm`, before glob expansion, not the one you expected. `eval` will apply the normal shell command parsing, I think leading to fewer surprises. There are other approaches (using arrays, for example) that are safer if this is a command being built up inside your script and not, e.g., a line read from a text file.